# Where is the trust store in JBOSS for a self-signed certificate?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, jboss, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have created a self-signed certificate on my server.

Now I need to import the certificate to the trust store so that the application .  If it was Tomcat, I would put it here:
%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts

Where is the equivalent in JBoss?  Where should I look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can put it into the %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts, or copy that file, add you cert and point to the new file with:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<<new_path>>cacerts
```